# Android SQLite: Update Statement

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need to implement SQLite in my application. I followed this tutorial:
[Creating and using databases in Android one](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesdatastorage/235-creating-and-using-databases-in-android-one)

Everything is working fine. I inserted 1 row with 5 columns.
Now I want to update the value of 1 column only and the others will remain the same.

There is one update method in the tutorial that needs all the parameters, however, I want to update only one column.

Comment: The requested URL /index.php/articlesdatastorage/235-creating-and-using-databases-in-android-one was not found on this server.

Answer (score 165):

You can use the code below.

```
String strFilter = "_id=" + Id;
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
myDB.update("titles", args, strFilter, null);
```

Comment: You could even do: myDB.update("titles", args, strFilter, new String[] { Integer.toString(ID) }); if you have strFilter set to "_id=?"... The annoying thing with a single item is that you still need to put it in an array, which can make it inconvenient. Still, up voted for the right answer.

Comment: @Dheeraj - This will only update the column which is added to the ContentValues object

Comment: If I'm not wrong, @joshhendo 's code should also prevent SQL injections, something this answer doesn't consider. Since the argument is passed as a parameter it is escaped by the underlying code.

Comment: You would need to put quotes around your `Id`. Something like:
`String strFilter = "_id='" + Id + "'";`

Answer (score 119):

**You can try:**

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE DB_TABLE SET YOUR_COLUMN='newValue' WHERE id=6 ");
```

Or

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put("YOUR_COLUMN", "newValue");

db.update("YOUR_TABLE", newValues, "id=6", null);
```

Or

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put("YOUR_COLUMN", "newValue");

String[] args = new String[]{"user1", "user2"};
db.update("YOUR_TABLE", newValues, "name=? OR name=?", args);
```

Answer (score 53):

It's all in the tutorial how to do that:

```
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(columnName, newValue);
    db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null);
```

Use `ContentValues` to set the updated columns and than the `update()` method in which you have to specifiy, the table and a criteria to only update the rows you want to update.

Comment: -1. The question is to update a single column in a row, not to update a whole row. [Alex's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5987911/165674) is correct.

Comment: Dheeraj, you can just add as many args.put(columnName, newValue) as you want.

Answer (score 18):

you can always execute SQL.

```
update [your table] set [your column]=value
```

for example

```
update Foo set Bar=125
```

Comment: Why using an explicit SQL statement, if there is an (pretty easy and convenient) API for that?

Comment: @Stephan : Because its not standard SQLite. The API ties up too much specially when the DB is shared between apps on different platforms

Comment: @Stephan This is the only correct answer to the question. The OP wants to update a single column in a row, not to update a whole row.

Comment: Using the API is a better bet here, I'm surprised there isn't a middle solution, the C library lets you define an SQL to execute and set formatters and tokens, the next step is using the C api to bind variables to the tokens in the SQL string, thus avoiding parsing errors and quote problems etc... here it's almost too assisted, not even writing even part of the SQL, doesn't feel nice... but rather this then a concatenated SQL string.

Comment: This method will fail when string contain single quotes and some special character. @Nike answer is correct.

Comment: Properly using the API will avoid a potential SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: @DheerajV.S. no it is not! It's an alterantive answer, yes. Updating a single column is perfectly possible by using the API.

Comment: how to do this when there are multiple records to update?

Answer (score 2):

I use this class to handle database.I hope it will help some one in future.

Happy coding.

```
public class Database {

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /**
     * Database name
     */
    private static final String DB_NAME = "db_name";

    /**
     * Table Names
     */
    public static final String TABLE_CART = "DB_CART";


    /**
     *  Cart Table Columns
     */
    public static final String CART_ID_PK = "_id";// Primary key

    public static final String CART_DISH_NAME = "dish_name";
    public static final String CART_DISH_ID = "menu_item_id";
    public static final String CART_DISH_QTY = "dish_qty";
    public static final String CART_DISH_PRICE = "dish_price";

    /**
     * String to create reservation tabs table
     */
    private final String CREATE_TABLE_CART = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_CART + " ( "
            + CART_ID_PK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + CART_DISH_NAME + " TEXT , "
            + CART_DISH_ID + " TEXT , "
            + CART_DISH_QTY + " TEXT , "
            + CART_DISH_PRICE + " TEXT);";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CART);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_TABLE_CART);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}


     /**
      * CART handler
      */
      public static class Cart {


    /**
     * Check if Cart is available or not
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isCartAvailable(Context context) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        boolean exists = false;

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();
        }

        return exists;
    }


    /**
     * Insert values in cart table
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dishName
     * @param dishPrice
     * @param dishQty
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean insertItem(Context context, String itemId, String dishName, String dishPrice, String dishQty) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_ID, "" + itemId);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME, "" + dishName);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_PRICE, "" + dishPrice);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_QTY, "" + dishQty);

        try {
            db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CART, null, values);
            db.close();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check for specific record by name
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dishName
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isItemAvailable(Context context, String dishName) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        boolean exists = false;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART + " WHERE "
                + DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME + " = '" + String.valueOf(dishName) + "'";


        try {
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
            cursor.close();

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            db.close();

        }

        return exists;
    }

    /**
     * Update cart item by item name
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dishName
     * @param dishPrice
     * @param dishQty
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean updateItem(Context context, String itemId, String dishName, String dishPrice, String dishQty) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_ID, itemId);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME, dishName);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_PRICE, dishPrice);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_QTY, dishQty);

        try {

            String[] args = new String[]{dishName};
            db.update(DBHelper.TABLE_CART, values, DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME + "=?", args);

            db.close();


            return true;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get cart list
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static ArrayList<CartModel> getCartList(Context context) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        ArrayList<CartModel> cartList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART + ";";

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

                cartList.add(new CartModel(
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_ID)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_QTY)),
                        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_PRICE)))
                ));
            }

            db.close();

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();
        }
        return cartList;
    }

   /**
     * Get total amount of cart items
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static String getTotalAmount(Context context) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        double totalAmount = 0.0;

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART + ";";

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

                totalAmount = totalAmount + Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_PRICE))) *
                        Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_QTY)));
            }

            db.close();


        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();
        }


        if (totalAmount == 0.0)
            return "";
        else
            return "" + totalAmount;
    }


    /**
     * Get item quantity
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dishName
     * @return
     */
    public static String getItemQty(Context context, String dishName) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART + " WHERE " + DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME + " = '" + dishName + "';";
        String quantity = "0";

        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                quantity = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_QTY));

                return quantity;
            }


        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return quantity;
    }


    /**
     * Delete cart item by name
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dishName
     */
    public static void deleteCartItem(Context context, String dishName) {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            String[] args = new String[]{dishName};
            db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_CART, DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME + "=?", args);

            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}//End of cart class

/**
 * Delete database table
 *
 * @param context
 */
public static void deleteCart(Context context) {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    try {

        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

**Usage:**

```
  if(Database.Cart.isCartAvailable(context)){

       Database.deleteCart(context);

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQLiteDatabase object depends on the type of operation on the database.

More information, visit the official website:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#UpdateDbRow

It explains how to manipulate consultations on the SQLite database.

#### INSERT ROW

Gets the data repository in write mode

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, id);
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTENT, content);
```

Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row

```
long newRowId;
newRowId = db.insert(
     FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
     FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE,
     values);
```

#### UPDATE ROW

Define 'where' part of query.

```
String selection = FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + " LIKE ?";
```

Specify arguments in placeholder order.

```
String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(rowId) };


SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

New value for one column

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);
```

Which row to update, based on the ID

```
String selection = FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + " LIKE ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(rowId) };
    int count = db.update(
    FeedReaderDbHelper.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
    values,
    selection,
    selectionArgs);
```

Comment: Although the linked website may contain an answer to the question, your answer seems incomplete. Links can expire or break in another way. Please add relevant code/information from the linked website to your answer.

Comment: Of course I understand, I just literally put the solution that worked for me and of course for its alleged source where I obtained