# How to replace old files with new files in android sqlite database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have build a application in which I am getting files and folders from server (using .net web services), i have class broadcast reciever in which i want to implement a method where app call services check whether new version is there or not and if yes then replace with new one in local sqlite database, which is I have created...
My question is how to replace old files with new one from server to local sqlite database?

Edit: Replace new files with old in phone storage.

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify. For example with the steps. Also 'which' local SQLite DB? The one from the app?

Comment: hi, yes Please let me know which part you don't understand and yes SQlite database sorry means my local phone storage, where I am downloading files and saving id and url into it.

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Downloading it to a folder. Or updating the database with a new url?

Comment: @RvdK updating data with new url?

Comment: @RvdK, Please do let me know how this thing is possible? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android SQLite: Update Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987863/android-sqlite-update-statement)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to update the local files on your local phone storage with new files that you retrieved from the web server, is that right??

To update the files locally, I am gonna assume you have two arrays of filepaths oldFilePaths and newFilePaths

I would just iterate and delete old ones and put the new ones something like this:

```
foreach(var oldFilePath in foldFilePaths)
{
    var oldFileName = Path.GetFileName(oldFilePath);
    // This assumes that your files (old and new Ones have the same name). 
    // And that you are saving your new files in a temporary folder.
    var newFilePath = newFilePaths.ToList().FirstOrDefault(f => Path.GetFileName(f) == oldFileName);
    if (newFilePath != null)
    {
        File.Delete(oldFilePath);
        File.Copy(newFilePath, oldFilePath);
    }
}
```

Now You could also just update the file Paths in the database. Assuming that you have a unique identifier for the 
file names in the database. To do that, you could do something like:

```
const string selectSqlQuery = "SELECT FileID, FilePath FROM FILES";
var updateSqlQuery = "UPDATE FILES SET FilePath = '{0}' WHERE FileID = '{1}'"; 
var oldFilesList = new List<MyFile>(); // assuming you have object of MyFile {Id, FilePath};

using(var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    // reading old files from Database
    using (var command = connection.Command())
    {
      command.CommandText = selectSqlQuery;
       IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
       while(reader.Read()) 
       {
            oldFilesList.Add(new MyFile { Id = reader["Id"], FilePath = reader["FilePath"] });
       }
    }

    // updating new filePaths, assuming that you have newFilesList from calling the web service
    foreach(var oldFile in oldFilesList)
    {
        var newFile = newFilesList.ToList().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == oldFile.Id);
        if (newFile != null)
        {
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = string.Format(updateSqlQuery, newFile.Id, newFile.FilePath);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

// The code above is in C# (MonoDroid) because that is what I use, and I do not think it is far from Java