# Android SQLite update statement

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I'm trying to update a single attribute in a a single row. However, the code I have below is updating every row with the value of 'new description'.

```
public void editSingleLocation(String id, String new_description){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
         newValues.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, new_description);
         db.update(TABLE_LOCATIONS, newValues, KEY_ID=id, null);
```

i was trying to use one of the solutions in this link [Android SQLite: Update Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987863/android-sqlite-update-statement)

but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it:

the problem was with "KEY_ID=id"; it needed to be changed to:

```
 db.update(TABLE_LOCATIONS, newValues, KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It looked like an information that would belong into the question (even more so before your edit).