# Updating database in android application using SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I followed this for updating my database: [Android SQLite: Update Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987863/android-sqlite-update-statement)

It works good, but when I run my application, it crashes by saying: unfortunately your app has stopped working.

Here is the output of my log:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: users (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE users SET total_usage=? WHERE email =myemail
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1688)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1636)
            at com.example.userX.theneckoptimizer.library.DatabaseHandler.updateUser(DatabaseHandler.java:92)
            at com.example.userX.theneckoptimizer.background$1.onFinish(background.java:101)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I start calling the update function when onFinish() is executed:

```
   public void onFinish() {
                MyActivity.amountOfVibrations= MyActivity.amountOfVibrations+ 1;
                Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibrator.vibrate(500); //0.5 seconds of vibration

                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                db.updateUser(RegisterActivity.email, "123456");
             } // email = myemail
```

The db.UpdateUser functions is as follows:

```
public void updateUser(String email, String total_usage) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String strFilter = "email =" + email;
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TOTAL_USAGE, total_usage);
    db.update("users", args, strFilter, null);

}
```

I try to update a row: total_usage, where column: email.

Updating some data is the most important part in my application.

Why the log gives this output:

```
while compiling: UPDATE users SET total_usage=? WHERE email =myemail
```

I really hope someone can help me. Im trying more than 10 hours to solve this issue..

Comment: are you sure, you typed the table name "users" correctly in both places?  ensure that it doesn't contain any additional spaces. can you post the code snippet that uses to register user?

Comment: I just solved the table name, thanks to CommonsWare

Comment: how? let us know how you solved?

Comment: In phpmyadmin, the table name was 'users'. In the Java file, it was defined at 'login'. Very but VERY dumb fault. But this happens when you try to solve issue hor hours long :\

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
String strFilter = "email =" + email;
```

to:

```
String strFilter = "email";
```

and change:

```
db.update("users", args, strFilter, null);
```

to:

```
db.update("users", args, strFilter, new String[] { email });
```

Comment: the log says: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: users (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE users SET total_usage=? WHERE email

This is a general issue, I checked nearly all questions, but still not solved. Thanks anyway for your time sir

Comment: Your previous answer was right. In the Java file, name was login and in phpmyadmin, the name was users. You were right by saying "how do u look to the name of the table". Thanks for your time