# Android SQLite Update Column

Tags: android, database, sqlite, transactions

User Case :

1. Select item by id, if its already present in the basket.
2. Check the numbers of this item.
3. If item numbers == 1 then delete this item from basket table and return 0.
4. If its greater than 1 then decrement it by one and update the table and return number-- .

Its not updating my "numbers" column, and silently passes through the execution and I am helpless nor can I post any stack trace here, but I am posting my code fragment, responsible for this job.

```
public int removeFromBasketasAnonymous(Long _id){

    Log.d("app : ", " _id = " + _id);
    int numbers = 0;
    try {
        database = openDatabaseInReadMode();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from basket where basket._id=" + _id + ";", null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Log.d(APP, "GetCount = " + cursor.getCount());
            if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
                //this item already present in basket
                numbers = cursor.getInt(1);
                Log.d(APP, " numbers  = " + numbers);
                Log.d(APP, "db id = " + cursor.getString(0));
                String[] columns = cursor.getColumnNames();
                for(String str : columns){
                    Log.d("APP ", " columns = "+str);
                }
                Log.d(APP, " id = " + _id);
                if (numbers == 1) {
                    //remove this row entry
                    cursor.close();

                    database.close();
                    database = openDatabaseInReadWriteMode();
                    database.beginTransaction();
                    String strSQL = "DELETE from basket where basket._id=" + _id;
                    try{
                        database.execSQL(strSQL);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{
                        database.endTransaction();
                        database.close();
                    }
                    numbers--;

                } else {
                    //decrement this number by one
                    Log.d(APP, " number " + numbers);
                    numbers--;
                    Log.d(APP, " dcremented numbers = " + numbers);
                    cursor.close();
                    database.close();
                    database = openDatabaseInReadWriteMode();
                    database.beginTransaction();
                    try{
                        ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
                        data.put("numbers", numbers);
                        database.update("basket", data, "_id = " + _id, null);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally {
                        database.endTransaction();
                        database.close();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }finally{
        if(database != null){
            database.close();
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}


public SQLiteDatabase openDatabaseInReadMode() {
    File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
    if (!isDataBaseExist()) {
        try {
            copyDatabase(dbFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
        }
    }
    /*Log.d("DB available", "path = " + dbFile.exists() + " path" + dbFile.getPath());*/
    /*Log.d("actual path ", "exists = " + isDataBaseExist());*/
    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}


public SQLiteDatabase openDatabaseInReadWriteMode() {
    File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
    if (!isDataBaseExist()) {
        try {
            copyDatabase(dbFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
        }
    }
    /*Log.d("DB available", "path = " + dbFile.exists() + " path" + dbFile.getPath());*/
    /*Log.d("actual path ", "exists = " + isDataBaseExist());*/
    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
```

Regards,
Shashank

Comment: why You can´t post the stacktrace?

Comment: Will this help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987863/android-sqlite-update-statement  but I did the same..

Comment: @Opiatefuchs , its silently passes through the code and numbers column is not updated.. when I run the same code again, number is still the same as previous.

Comment: there could so many causes for this problem, that´s why it is important to see the stacktrace.

Comment: try to use `database.setTransactionSuccessful();` after update statement

Comment: If you did "Select *", how do you know what column are you reading in the line "numbers = cursor.getInt(1);" ?

Comment: @saurabh bans, It solves the problem.. I want to give you upvote. Thanks for your quick and nice answer.

Comment: @jekeyeke , table "order" has only two column( _id, numbers), I am really sorry, I gave incomplete information.

Comment: @sourabh bans , please post your answer, I will accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How you can use database transaction in Android**

1. If you want to start the transaction there is a method `beginTransaction()`
2. If you want to commit the transaction there is a
   method `setTransactionSuccessful()` which will commit the values in the
   database
3. If you had start the transaction you need to close the transaction so there is a method `endTransaction()` which will end your database transaction

**Now there are two main points**

1. If you want to set transaction successful you need to write
   `setTransactionSuccessful()` and then `endTransaction()` after
   beginTransaction()
2. If you want to rollback your transaction then you need to `endTransaction()` 
   without committing the transaction by `setTransactionSuccessful()`.