# onclick update value in a row in sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi I'm new to Android Java and SQLite, I'm trying to make an onClick listener change the value in the column from 1 to 2 but I'm confused about what I need to do. I tried doing some research on it but seem to get the basic way of updating your entries you added. Can anyone help me with this?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if (database.updateReserved() == 1) {
                database.updateReserved(reserved);
                }


            }
        });

 public  void updateReserved(Integer reserved){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("reserved",reserved);
        String tableName="cars"; //Table Name
        db.update(tableName , contentValues, "=" + reserved,null) ;

    }
```

Comment: What is going wrong when you try this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android SQLite: Update Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987863/android-sqlite-update-statement)

Comment: im still kinda confused on what i need to do

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that only rows with `reserved = 1` will be updated, change `updateReserved()` so that both the current value and the new value of `reserved` are passed as arguments.
So, in the 3d argument of `update()`, which is the `WHERE` clause, pass the current value:

```
public void updateReserved(int oldReserved, int newReserved) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("reserved", newRreserved);
    String tableName = "cars"; 
    db.update(tableName, contentValues, "reserved = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(oldReserved)}) ;
}
```

Now you can simplify the click listener like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        database.updateReserved(1, reserved);
    }
});
```